# Convention for "my class" in class method

Tags: python, coding-style, naming-conventions

For example, I have two class methods in a class, one calling other.

```
class MyClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def foo(insert_name_here):
        print "foo."

    @classmethod
    def bar(insert_name_here):
        insert_name_here.foo()
```

`c` is obviously too short.  Funny words like `kind`, `myclass`, `such` come into my mind, but at the end of the day consistency is the winner.

What is the correct convention?  Or more generally, what is the authoritative source for finding such?  Is there a PEP for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention is to call the class parameter `cls`.

See [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments):

> Function and method arguments
>
> Always use `self` for the first argument to instance methods.
> Always use `cls` for the first argument to class methods.

Answer (score 2):

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says:

> Always use cls for the first argument to class methods.

```
class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print "foo."

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        cls.foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

[PEP8 says `cls`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments)

> ### Function and method arguments
>
> Always use `self` for the first argument to instance methods.
>
> Always use `cls` for the first argument to class methods.
>
> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is
>   generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than
>   use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus `class_` is better than
>   `clss`. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)